# Why would a polar protic solvent favor the addition of HBr to an alkene?

Tags: organic-chemistry, solvents

I understand that a polar solvent will help dissociate the $\ce{HBr}$ into ions.

But why a protic solvent?

Why would we want a solvent that would encage the $\ce{Br}$ and $\ce{H}$ ions?

Why is the aprotic solvent not favored? My textbook does not discuss this and I searched online, with no result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> why a protic solvent?

Protic solvents tend to have higher dielectric constants than typical, **unreactive**, non-protic solvents.  Look at the following table.

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}\hline
\text{Solvent} & \text{Dielectric constant}    \\ \hline
\text{methanol} & 32.6    \\ \hline
\text{ethanol} & 24.6   \\ \hline
\text{methylene chloride} & 9.08 \\ \hline
\text{chlorobenzene} & 5.69\\ \hline
\text{chloroform} & 4.81    \\ \hline
\text{diethyl ether} & 4.27    \\ \hline
\end{array}

The higher dielectric constant stabilizes ions which means that 1) $\ce{HBr}$ will tend to be more dissociated and 2) (as Dissenter noted) the resultant carbocation intermediate will be more stabilized thereby lowering the energy of the transition state leading to it.

Comment: Propylene carbonate: 64; Acetonitrile: 39; dimethylformamide: 38; HMPT: 30

Comment: @AbelFriedman  That's why I highlighted **unreactive**.  I don't know the reaction conditions we're discussing, but acid-catalyzed hydration of a nitrile would be a distinct possibility.

Comment: @AbelFriedman, (and @Dissenter), ron seems to agree with my textbook like Dissenter. I'm confused :O

Comment: @AbelFriedman  Yes, propylene carbonate, DMF and HMPT are also subject to acid hydrolysis and could generate by-products that would contaminate the reaction.

Answer (score 2):

A polar protic solvent will help stabilize the carbocation that is formed in the process of electrophilic addition. When the nucleophilic $\pi$ bond grabs the hydrogen from the $\ce{HBr}$, one of the carbons that was part of the $\pi$ bond is left deficient of an octet.

Answer (score 2):

High-dielectric solvent assist dissociation because they shield charge.  Since the proton's electric field is so high, it always finds a base to bind to, which will in your case be $\ce{Br-}$.  So you also have to consider the solvent's basicity.  Read [this article](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/j100139a045).

The assertion that you need a protic solvent is wrong, you need a sufficiently basic solvent.